# Debugging keyboard events like 'Ctrl+Up Arrow'

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

I want to debug a part of a program that is intended to respond to keyboard input such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

So, I put a breakpoint in the code in the area interest. However, once I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key the program jumps to that breakpoint. This happens *before* I have pressed an arrow key, so I'm finding this situation difficult to debug.

So, how can I debug a multi-key input event such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio to debug your code, you can debug this situation by adding a *condition* to your breakpoint.

To do so, right-click the break point icon to the left of your code statement and click *`Condition...`* An example of a condition that would apply to your situation is:

```cs
e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up
```

Now you can debug multi-key input events such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> without the need to change any of your code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) to write debug information to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection.

Example:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Up with control have pressed");
}
```

In the Visual Studio menu bar, select View->Output to see the output.

Answer (score 2):

What event do you use? KeyDown? Try using KeyUp. It won't fire until you release CTRL+key combination.

Comment: KEY-UP solved my problem. but sorry I picked another answer as correct just because it was closer to the question that I had asked. but to solve my real problem I got the Key-Up idea from your post.

Comment: LOL I don't understand why the marked-as-answer post is closer to your question while my idea solved the problem, but OK :) Let it be. You can vote me up at least :)

Answer (score 2):

How about just putting the breakpoint inside the `if` clause? That way it only breaks if the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) method. It will allow you to only go to debug based on a condition. Execution will continue until the condition is false. You could do something like (pseudo-code): `Debug.Assert(NOT up key pressed);`
This will make it ignore any key presses but the up key.

Answer (score 1):

In general your only option is to print some messages to console or error log. Otherwise debugger UI will interfere with your code. Visual Studio debugger, for example, can print values of expressions on hitting breakpoint, so you don't need to write special code.

Comment: ", can print values of expressions on hitting breakpoint, so you don't need to write special code."  ... what is that? How ?

Comment: @BDotA on breakpoint press right mouse button, select "when hit", you will see a window with instructions. Hit "print message" and "continue execution" checkboxes and enter your expression, like: "variable: {myVar}", so value of the myVar will be printed to output window on hitting this breakpoint.